# Why does SQL Server prefer >= 1 over > 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've always been told that the inclusive comparison is better than the exclusive, but it's never been explained why.

Is it purely from a performance perspective or is there another reason why `>= 1` is better than `> 0` ?

Comment: With SQL Databases, take every absolute piece of advice with a grain of salt. It's far better to use the *actual performance tuning tools*, **when** you have a performance problem to solve, than to write unnatural code in the (unproven) belief that it'll magically perform better than a plainer alternative.

Comment: For reference, I've never heard this specific piece of advice and I have *never* encountered a performance problem that came down to a range comparison that wasn't solved by indexing rather than changing the exact form of the comparison.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I suspect that it's an assembly thing, q.v. my answer.  Not sure that it matters in practice.

Comment: I strongly doubt it's for performance reasons. Consider that `x BETWEEN 1 AND 3` is equivalent to `x >= 1 AND x <= 3`, but also to `x > 0 AND x < 4`. The former is more intuitive to most, while the latter looks better to golfcoders.

Comment: There is a lot of nonsense spoken about SQL performance. Looks like whoever told you that participates in this. It may be the case that once they found that changing the predicate in this manner sped things up but likely the underlying reason would have been something like parameter sniffing where **any** change to the query text would have helped

Comment: I agree with @MartinSmith The same source probably also claims that `count(1)` is faster than `count(*)` or `where exists (select 1 ...)` is faster than `where exists (select * ...)`

Comment: ..this was definitely true for sybase ASE..

Comment: @lptr - care to elaborate on why that was beneficial in that product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is a complete myth.

**Let me explain why:**

When you seek an index with an inequality, you get a range seek. In other words, the server seeks to the start point, and moves forward to the end point (if any).

> We assume that there are no rows between `0` and `1`, say `0.5`, otherwise the resultset is not the same.

So when you use `WHERE IndexColumn >= 1`, the server seeks down the B-Tree to the first row with `1`. And when you use `WHERE IndexColumn > 0`, the server seeks to *after* the end point of all `0` rows.

If the next row after `0` is a `1` then they are seeking to the same place, **ergo the performance will be exactly the same.**

Statistics-wise, they will also get similar estimates, because the calculation ends up being almost exactly the same.

---

If there is no index then you are doing a full scan, in which case you are dependent on the CPU taking the same time for `>` as for `>=`, which I believe is true for all modern processors.

---

**As a rule of thumb, treat all rules-of-thumb you hear about SQL with a big pinch of salt.** SQL performance is far more dependent on things like good indexing and sarge-ability.